# Unable to click on dropdown list option after list is displayed automatically for NetSuite

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am trying to simply click on the dropdown list that is displayed after I enter the word advance. But I keep getting an error being thrown. Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:

```
 public void supplier (WebDriver driver)
    {
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement supplierLink = driver.findElement(By.id("_searchstring"));
        supplierLink.sendKeys("Advance");
        
        //*[@id="/app/accounting/transactions/transactionlist.nl?Transaction_TYPE=Custom108"]
        //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5); 
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//app/accounting/transactions/transactionlist.nl?Transaction_TYPE=Custom108")));
        
        WebElement clickadvance = driver.findElement(By.id("/app/accounting/transactions/transactionlist.nl?Transaction_TYPE=Custom108"));
        action.moveToElement(clickadvance).perform();
        
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Which option you want to select from populated option ?

Comment: I am trying to select - Page: Advance

Comment: Can you share the HTML for the same in text format. go to that option in HTML, and do right click and select outer HTML.

Comment: <a role="option" class="uir-item-view" href="/app/accounting/transactions/transactionlist.nl?Transaction_TYPE=Custom108" id="/app/accounting/transactions/transactionlist.nl?Transaction_TYPE=Custom108">Page: <span>Advance</span></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add wait conditions in your code, this will work,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
By optionXpath = By.id("/app/accounting/transactions/transactionlist.nl?Transaction_TYPE=Custom108");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(optionXpath));
driver.findElement(optionXpath).click();
```

if not your xpath is wrong, change the xpath accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this xpath

```
//span[text()='Advance']/parent::a[@role='option' and contains(@id,'/app/accounting/transactions/transactionlist.nl?')]
```

Please make sure it should represent the correct element.

**Code trial 1 :**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Advance']/parent::a[@role='option' and contains(@id,'/app/accounting/transactions/transactionlist.nl?')]"))).click();
```